# ContentResolver returns outdated data

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

The following code should return the last phone number in the call log.

It mostly works, but sometimes it returns not the last phone number, but the second last. If I check the list of calls, I can clearly see that the number returned is not the last in the history. Running the program again will return the last ("correct") number.

Can anyone tell what's wrong?

```
private String getPhoneNumber() {
    String[] projection = {CallLog.Calls.NUMBER};
    Cursor callLog = getContentResolver().query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
    );

    // Set number
    callLog.moveToFirst();
    return callLog.getString(callLog.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
}
```

Comment: you should `close()` your cursor when you have finished with it